# Azure Logic App, parallelism and blob write

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have a simple logic app, the purpose of it is to receive messages from a service bus and write the messages into a blob file.

```
Receive from queue (auto complete) -> Get Blob Content -> Update Blob (append)
```

In testing, when the service bus queue has a lot of messages to process, the blob is missing some of the messages. I guess that running XX concurrent instances means the data gets lost. Changing the Concurrency Control doesn't help.

Am I doing this the correct way?

Or

How do I test to see if one of the other instances has the blob open at the time?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using peek-lock with "complete the message" in the end after a successful operation?
[image]

Few suggestions,
use peek-lock.
consider using "forward dead letter message" to another queue where you can retry sending again
add some try-catch logic to see why it failed.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but adapting my flow this way still misses data with Concurrency is over 1.